# How do I put semaphores (semops) in the right order?

Tags: c

I have this piece of code about semaphores and IPC mechanism here:

```
struct sembuf op={0, -1, 0};

int main()
{
    int shm_id, sem_id;
    key_t key;
    pid_t pid;
    int seconds;

    key=ftok("/bin/ls", '1');
    shm_id=shmget(key, 2048, IPC_CREAT|0666);
    sem_id=semget(key, 1, IPC_CREAT|0666);
    shmem=(char *)shmat(shm_id, NULL, 0);

    strcpy(shmem, "Let  say: ");
    printf("welcome Hello\n");
    pid=fork();
    printf(" burned");
    srand((unsigned int)pid+100);
    seconds=rand()%2;
    sleep(seconds);

    if(pid>0)
    {
        semop(sem_id, &op, 1);
        sprintf(shmem, "Im father pid=%d", (int)getpid());
    }
    else
    {
        printf(" recv: '%s'\n", shmem);
    }
    printf(" finish\n");
    if(pid>0)
    {
        wait(NULL);
        shmdt(shmem);
        shmctl(shm_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
        semctl(sem_id, 0, IPC_RMID);
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

How do I replace the semop, so all of the printfs work in the right positioning? Maybe I need to add another struct which can add the semaphore number? Can you please help?

I am new to this mechanic, tried only once and understood it poorly. I wanna print out:
welcome Hello
burned recv: 'Let  say: Im father pid= his pid'
finish
But I can't do it right and it always prints out wither one of them or the other and doesn't print finish.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow is generally: Lock resource; Use resource; Unlock resource. The parent process doesn't unlock the semaphore, and the child-process doesn't even check the semaphore.

I suggest you "lock" the semaphore *before* you fork. Then in the parent process you directly write to the shared memory followed by "unlocking" the semaphore.

In the child process you attempt to "lock" the semaphore (which should block until the parent process have "unclocked" it), then read from the shared memory, followed by its own "unlock" of the semaphore.

--

In ***pseudo*** code, perhaps something like this:

```
shm = create_share_memory(...);
sem = create_semaphore(1);  // Note initial value is 1

// Because the initial value of the semaphore is 1 it's
// considered "locked"

if (fork() == 0)
{
    // In parent process, with the semaphore already locked
    snprintf(shm, "...");

    // Decrease the semaphore to 0
    // This will "unlock" it
    decrease_semaphore(sem);
}
else
{
    // In the child process

    // If the semaphore isn't zero, wait for it to become zero
    // Then increase the semaphore
    // This waits for the semaphore to become "unlocked",
    // and then lock it immediately
    wait_and_increase_semaphore(sem);

    read_shared_memory(shm);

    // "Unlock" the semaphore
    decrease_semaphore(sem);
}
```

Comment: Didn't really understand what you said, sorry about it. Can you please give a more detailed explanation for newbies?